# Django, python, redis sorting

Tags: python, django, caching, redis

I used redis to sort out the most viewed items in a project I am working on. I would like to sort out only the most viewed for the day and out the overall most viewed. In other words, viewing count should restart everyday. Here is my code

```
@login_required
def image_ranking(request):
    image_ranking = r.zrange('image_ranking', 0, -1, desc=True[:110000]
    image_ranking_ids = [int(id) for id in image_ranking]
    most_viewed = list(Image.objects.filter(id__in=image_ranking_ids))
    most_viewed.sort(key=lambda x: image_ranking_ids.index(x.id))
    paginator = Paginator(most_viewed, 24)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        most_viewed = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        most_viewed = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        if request.is_ajax():
            return HttpResponse('')
        most_viewed = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    if request.is_ajax():
        return render(request, 'images/image/ranking_ajax', {'section': 'images', 'most_viewed': most_viewed})
    return render(request, 'images/image/ranking.html', {'section': 'images', 'most_viewed': most_viewed})
```

Comment: what are the problems are you facing?

Comment: I mean I want to expire and restart counting of views everyday